# set static percentage after action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a game which will have a crime function based on success percentages. The success percentage builds as the player executes actions.

Right now, I generate random % based on successful and failed action. However, this results in the percentage changing each time loading the page. Is there a way to make this percentage static after the action has been commited?

This is my code:

Controller:

```
private ViewModelCrime GetChances(UserGangster gangster) {
        var cm = new ViewModelCrime();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            cm.SelectedCrime = (ViewModelCrime.Crime)i;
            double d6 = (cm.ChanceMultiplier * gangster.GansterStatistic.CrimesSuccess     * (_rnd.Next(90, 105) / 100)) + ((cm.ChanceMultiplier *     gangster.GansterStatistic.CrimesFailed / (_rnd.Next(380, 420) / 100)));
            double finalD2 = LimitSuccesPercentage(cm.SelectedCrime, d6);

            cm.SuccesPercentage.Add((ViewModelCrime.Crime)i, finalD2);
```

Model:

```
public double ChanceMultiplier {
        get {
            switch (SelectedCrime) {
                case Crime.Crime01:
                    return 0.1;
                case Crime.Crime02:
                    return 0.08;
                case Crime.Crime03:
                    return 0.04;
                case Crime.Crime04:
                    return 0.0035;
                case Crime.Crime05:
                    return 0.0015;
                case Crime.Crime06:
                    return 0.0008;
                case Crime.Crime07:
                    return 0.0005;
                case Crime.Crime08:
                    return 0.0002;
                case Crime.Crime09:
                    return 0.0001;
                default:
                    return 0.0001;

            }
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<Crime, double> SuccesPercentage{
        get { return _succesPercentage; }
        set { _succesPercentage = value; }
```

On the view I use one line to show the %

View:

```
@string.Format("{0:P0}",Model.SuccesPercentage[(ViewModelCrime.Crime)9])
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure to understand when do you want this percentage to be static ? Well, i'm not even sure why you want a %age to be random, since it will already be used to generate a random success ^^

Comment: The code now generates a variable success percentage after loading the page. I'd like to change that and make the success percentage static after committing the action, so when a player refreshes or visits the page again, it will not change.

Comment: Well, then you need a kind of storage for remembering that. You can pretty much go with any kind of database since the use case is so simple. Then in your code, you have to have an architecture which says "Check the storage, if nothing there, generate the %age, and store it".

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'll look into it and see if I can get it fixed.